# Alignment on Telerik Scheduler is getting further and further out of line from header?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik-scheduler

I'm new to using the Telerik/Kendo tools (ASP.NET MVC), and I'm trying to create a Scheduler to show some deliveries.  However, I'm showing the days getting progressively further and further out of line from the header

I'm using Google Chrome 97.0.4692.99, though the same issue exists in Microsoft Edge, and build 2022.1.119 for the Telerik controls.

I'm not using any custom CSS at this point, but as you can see in the attached screenshot, each day starts getting further and further out of line with the date header.  This issue exists in Week and Timeline Week views (as shown)

Also, as a side question, is there any way to stop stacking these events side by side when they happen at the same time?  If I choose all day, they'll stack on top of each other, but when a time is involved, it seems like only side by side is allowed which makes things difficult to read.

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a bug (per developers @ Telerik)